# Is it possible to add a console application in a WCF service solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, console-application, projects-and-solutions

I am currently creating a WCF service application using Visual studio 2010. 
Is it possible to add a console application as a new project in the same WCF service solution?

Comment: Solutions are only a organizational object, where you put everything related. You can mix any kind of project in the same solution, if you have the correct edition of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Just add a Console application project to your solution.